# Fazer um Filter Input com key de array

Tags: php

Estou recebendo dados de um formulário, e tem um campo que é vem em array do `$_POST` que é assim:

```
Array
(
    [image_ids] => Array
        (
            [0] => 831
            [1] => 789
        )
)
```

E quero pegar o valor por `filter_input` desta maneira:

```
$images = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'image_ids');
```

e não consigo, alguém tem alguma ideia de como pego esses valores?

OBS: a variável images retorna `False` quando dou `var_dump`

Comment: Por que não consegue? Dá algum erro? Qual o valor final de `$images`?

Comment: Ele retorna false

Comment: Já tentou com o filtro `FILTER_REQUIRE_ARRAY`?

Comment: Não, vou testar agora que você falou

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss coloquei assim e ainda veio como false:

Comment: filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'image_ids', FILTER_REQUIRE_ARRAY)

Answer (score 0):

Coloquei esse código e funcionou:

```
$filters = array(
        'image_ids' => array(
             'filter' => FILTER_VALIDATE_INT,
             'flags' => FILTER_REQUIRE_ARRAY
        )
);
$images = filter_input_array(INPUT_POST, $filters);
```